# How do i print strings with indentations?

Tags: python, string, loops

I need to write a function that prints a string "Add Oil!" a number of n times with increasing indentations by 5 spaces in a new line.
This is the code that i tried to write... The problem is that im trying to create 5 spaces but i cannot use any operators since it's inside the quotation marks. Any other way to solve this?

```
def printAddOils(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print("Add Oil! \n " "*5*i")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def printAddOils(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print("1" * 5 * i, "Add Oil! \n ", sep='') # replace 1
printAddOils(3)
```

output:

```
11111Add Oil! 
 
1111111111Add Oil! 
 
111111111111111Add Oil!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def printAddOils(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print("".join([" "]*5*i)+"Add Oil!")
```

Explanation the syntax [" "]*x creates an array repeating the array x times.
Then you get an array of 5*i spaces. Then syntax "c".join(arr) will make a string by concatenating elements of the array using character c (or no character).

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in textwrap library if you need more flexibility or do a simple join to create the string yourself

```
import textwrap
def printAddOils(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(textwrap.indent("Add Oil!", "     "*i))
printAddOils(10)


def printAddOils2(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print("".join("     "*i) + "Add Oil!")
printAddOils2(10)

#      Add Oil!
#           Add Oil!
#                Add Oil!
#                     Add Oil!
#                          Add Oil!
#                               Add Oil!
#                                    Add Oil!
#                                         Add Oil!
#                                              Add Oil!
#                                                   Add Oil!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def printAddOils(n):
    sp=''
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(sp+"Add Oil! \n")
        sp+='    '
        
printAddOils(5)

Add Oil! 

Add Oil! 

    Add Oil! 

        Add Oil! 

            Add Oil!
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.6 onward you can use [fstrings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
def printAddOils(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        print(f"{5*i*' '}" + "Add Oil! \n ")
```